# run mupdf android demo error

Tags: android, android-ndk, mupdf

I have downloaded mupdf library to open pdf files from inside my own android app
then I have imported ChoosePDFActivity inside eclipse and when I run it and try to open a pdf file from sd card I have the following error :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load mupdf from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/com.artifex.mupdfdemo-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/com.artifex.mupdfdemo-2]: findLibrary returned null
```

I have searched in internet and found some tuto like that : [http://dixitpatel.com/integrating-pdf-in-android-application/](http://that)
but I diddn't know happen to do this step :

> Step 5 : ‘cd’ to folder: ‘ mupdf' than command: ‘make' (will take
>   about 40 sec. to run all scripts)

how can I achieve this

Comment: Are you on Windows, OS X or Linux?

Comment: You probably need the Android NDK installed.

Comment: I achieved this opening pdf file from my own app using mupdf, please use Android studio to do this easily and check this [link](https://github.com/tekinarslan/AndroidPdfViewer) its completely running demo.